# C++ Passing a function that's in a class to another function

Tags: c++, lua

I'm trying to use lua_pushcfunction (Using lua 5.2). I have the struct

```
class readFunctions {
    private:
        std::ifstream file;

    public:
       static int readAll(lua_State*);
};

int readFunctions::readAll(lua_State *L){
    std::string line;
    std::string nam;
    while (std::getline(file, line)) {
        nam = nam + line;
    }

    std::cout << nam;

    return 1;
}
readFunctions hand;
```

I use `lua_pushcfunction(lua_state, hand.readAll)` and get `error: argument of type 'int (readFunctions::)(lua_State*)' does not match 'lua_CFunction {aka int (*)(lua_State*)}'|`

How would I pass a method from a class to a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
lua_pushcfunction(lua_state, & readFunctions::readAll);
```

readAll is static so you dont need an instance; and you need its address not just the function  (a function is like a value, so you need to give pushcfunction its address). However I can't remember if compiler will accept `int (readFunctions::*)(lua_State*)` as a `int (*)(lua_State*)`, I have a feeling it might not but can't test it right now.

If you don't want a static method but a regular method: the method is part of an object (class instance), so to call it you need a `this` pointer; that won't work. But what might work is to use your static `readFunctions::readAll`, but when you call that function, the first parameter can be a light user data that is the `readFunctions` instance that you want to call.

Comment: I had forgotten I made that static.  It can't access file when it's static.  Is there a way to do it without making it static?